# Is it a good practice to write all javascript in the html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed a website and for that website I have separate pages for html and javascript. I'm including multiple ".js" files in the html page.Is it a good practice to do this or should I combine all the code in the html page?Which will give me better performance .

Comment: It depends on wether you use HTTP or HTTP/2 to fetch your scripts. If you use HTTP then you should bundle all your files into 1 js file and include that in the HTML with a `script` tag. If you use HTTP/2 then it doesn't matter how many files you include.

Comment: Hi @baruch , My site is using HTTP,not HTTP/2. So,you are suggesting it is better for me to write all the code in the same page?

Comment: Not in the page, but in a JS file and include that file in the page. And you don't need to write all your code in one file, you can have multiple files, but you'll have to bundle it with something like webpack or rollup.

Comment: @Baruch. Awesome.. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what *sort* of performance you're looking for.

If you include all Javascript on the page itself, first-time users will be served everything necessary on the first pageload, rather than having to make a separate network request for every `.js`. You see this often enough in the wild, even on extremely popular sites like Google: including the Javascript in the served HTML may result in more "wasted" bandwidth, because the inline `<script>` can't be cached like a `.js` can, but if bandwidth isn't an issue you're worried about, and you *really* want first-time users to be able to interact with the site ASAP, putting the script inline can help a bit, especially if latency is an issue (though it often isn't).

Both methods are viable. That said:

> I'm including multiple ".js" files in the html page

This means that clients will have to make a separate request for *every* file. You might consider using a module bundler like Webpack, so that you just have *one big* `.js` to serve to visitors instead, so that they only have to make one additional request, rather than 2 or 3 or more.

Using a module bundler has the additional benefit of (often) not polluting the global scope, which individual `<script src`s will often result in.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'll use WebPack and check again :)